# Bootstrap 4 Card Component Remove unnecessary whitespace

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so I'm using the card component from BS4 , however it's having some unexpected behaviour : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x45K.png)

so basically this is what I see on the mozilla dev version. the markup is as follows :

```
                       <div class="right-cards   col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                            <div class="card " id="first-card">
                                <a id="first_card_btn" class="btn-none" style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;display:block;'
                                    onclick="myFunction(this.id)"></a>
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/370" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4>contact us</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

the problem is that I need the card-body to be on top of the image - I know how to put that there, however I can't seem to get rid of the excess whitespace no matter what I tried.

Comment: Can you share your code in a jsfiddle? I'm sure it's a simple fix and it would be better to help you with your actual code and what you have already built :)

Comment: " no matter what I tried" what have you tried exactly?

Comment: you forgot to put your css btw (as @IvanS95 said)

Comment: Keep in mind that the Bootstrap Card has an explicit size, so you would have to either adjust the size of your image to use the size available in the card, or adjust the card so it takes the space of your image like this: codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/QzwKRN

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x1pw9j04/1/ here's a quick fiddle basically what the problem is that the card body moves up , however that whitespace is somehow part of the column itself

Comment: @vincent-d I tried with the spacing utilities and setting hardcoded sizes , however hardcoded height is not an answer I'm seeking for if i can avoid it... for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code I was able to add a few CSS rules to make it work like this, let me know if that works for you! Borders are just for you to see the space used for each element

```css
.card{
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.card-img-top {
 border: 1px solid green; 
}
.card-body{
 position: absolute;
 padding:0px !important;
 background-color:#3B9F2F;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 100%;
 top: 60%;
}

.right-cards {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
  <div class = row>
     <div class="right-cards col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
         <div class="card " id="first-card">
            <a id="first_card_btn" class="btn-none"  onclick="myFunction(this.id)"></a>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/370" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4>Contact us </h4>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly ! Thank you so much , but for future reference why is the position absolute fixing position relative? I'm not aware that much of the difference

Comment: No problem! For the positioning, the simplest way to say it would be that *relative* positions the element based on itself, so when you add for example `top: 20px`, it will move it 20px from its initial position; if you use *absolute* it will use its parent's starting point as reference (which needs to be positioned as well), then if you use `top: 20px` it will move the element 20px starting from the beginning of its parent element... Its kind of confusing without an example lol, you can read more about this here: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: This is also a great article and explains it really clearly: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-understand-css-position-absolute-once-and-for-all-b71ca10cd3fd

Comment: @VictorBonchevski remember to mark this as an accepted answer so others can benefit from it :)

Comment: Note, there is no longer `xs` in Bootstrap 4

Comment: @Zim true, hadn't noticed the `xs` class there